# Ejabberd gets very slow while MUC has over 20k subscribers

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

We are currently trying to make a real time chat for our current product based on ejabberd, so we are testing ejabberd based on some use cases.

Now we are running into a problem that while we sub more then 20K (our goal is at least 100K sub to a single MUC) user using rtb to a single MUC, message send in that MUC will have a very huge delay (10~15 second), is there any possible reason why is this happening or are we doing anything wrong?

we've tried turn on `user_mucsub_from_muc_archive` and `use_mam_for_storage` to ease loading on our mysql but it doesn't seems to help that much

below are our settings

```
mod_mam: 
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ##db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: always
    clear_archive_on_room_destroy: true
    user_mucsub_from_muc_archive: true
mod_muc: 
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      mam: true
      persistent: true
      allow_subscription: true
    max_users: 5000
    history_size: 0
mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
    use_mam_for_storage: true
```

Comment: have you tried an SQL or other non-Mnesia DB?